# Laravel User Auth Relationship Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How I can get another table with auth login? And how I can show the data of table in view? I'm trying relationship, but I don't know if is correct...

```
class Login extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = "users";

    public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserProfile::class)->select('id', 'photo', 'friendly_url');
    }
```

This return relations null:
dd(auth()->user())

```
Login {#307 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #relations: []
```

Comment: Are you logged in when you try? Also I believe it's Auth::user() not auth()->user()

Comment: @LewisJohnson they will do the same thing, one is a facade, one is a laravel helper method.

Answer (score 0):

`relations` property for model shows only loaded relationships.

To load relation for authorized user model use [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->load('userProfile');
dd($user->userProfile);
```

Then you can refer user profile data in your view as:

```
$user->userProfile->friendly_url
```

Also I recommend you to call this relation `profile()` instead of `userProfile()` to avoid repeating the 'user' word.

And the best solution - to keep user profile data in `users` table. This is much simpler, and reduces the number of requests to the database in your case.